# Double GroupBy with Count and Dates Returns Wrong Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables to keep track of emails and their assigned categories: `Email` keeps the mail's content, `Category` lists the categories and `Classification` links an `Email` entry ID with a `Category` entry ID. Schema with sample data and query is available on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a410a6/26/0

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Mail` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Classification` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mail_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (mail_id) REFERENCES Mail(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Important'),
  ('2', 'Urgent'),
  ('3', 'Normal');

INSERT INTO `Mail` (`id`, `content`, `date`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Important Email', '2019-01-04T13:53:52'),
  ('2', 'Urgent Email', '2019-01-19T13:53:52'),
  ('3', 'Very Urgent Email', '2019-01-24T13:53:52'),
  ('4', 'Quite Urgent Email', '2019-01-24T13:53:52'),
  ('5', 'Normal Email', '2019-01-21T13:53:52'),
  ('6', 'Regular Email', '2019-01-14T13:53:52'),
  ('7', 'Regular Email', '2019-01-23T13:53:52'),
  ('8', 'Regular Email', '2019-01-23T13:53:52'),
  ('9', 'Regular Email', '2019-01-20T13:53:52'),
  ('10', 'Very Urgent Email', '2019-01-25T13:53:52'),
  ('11', 'Very Urgent Email', '2019-01-25T13:53:52');


INSERT INTO `Classification` (`id`, `mail_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1'),
  ('2', '2', '2'),
  ('3', '3', '2'),
  ('4', '4', '2'),
  ('5', '5', '3'),
  ('6', '6', '3'),
  ('7', '6', '3'),
  ('8', '6', '3'),
  ('9', '6', '3'),
  ('10', '6', '2'),
  ('11', '6', '2');
```

I want to return the number of mails received for each category for each date recorded, i.e. my expected results would be

```
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
|         date         |   name    | count(*) |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2019-01-04T13:53:52Z | Important |        1 |
| 2019-01-14T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        1 |
| 2019-01-19T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        1 |
| 2019-01-20T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        1 |
| 2019-01-21T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        1 |
| 2019-01-23T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        2 |
| 2019-01-24T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        1 |
| 2019-01-25T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        2 |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
```

To do so I run the following query with a double groupby, filtering on the `Classification` table:

```
SELECT Mail.date, Category.name, count(*) FROM Mail, Classification, Category WHERE Category.id = Classification.category_id AND Classification.mail_id = Mail.id GROUP BY Mail.date, Category.name
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
|         date         |   name    | count(*) |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2019-01-04T13:53:52Z | Important |        1 |
| 2019-01-14T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        4 |
| 2019-01-14T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        2 |
| 2019-01-19T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        1 |
| 2019-01-21T13:53:52Z | Normal    |        1 |
| 2019-01-24T13:53:52Z | Urgent    |        2 |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
```

Which is entirely wrong.

I've tried substituting the `WHERE` statement for a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Mail.date, Category.name, count(*) FROM (Mail, Category) RIGHT JOIN Classification ON Category.id = Classification.category_id AND Classification.mail_id = Mail.id GROUP BY Mail.date, Category.name `
```

But I get the exact same results as above.

Why are those queries returning these erroneous results and what should I do to fix them ?

Comment: A good tip is: NEVER use comma join.

Comment: Your data model is incorrect, mail should have a foreign key to Classification, not the other way around

Comment: Joakim is correct in this instance, because obviously it's nonsensical for a mail to belong to more than one category (non-urgent and urgent, say), but if the categories were 'urgent','family','business', then of course the model would be reasonable- EXCEPT, that a mail couldn't belong to the same category twice, which is where your dataset is going wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is a schematic simplification of a data model I have to work with, so I can not change it. I would nonetheless love to understand why the current model is wrong if you care to expand.

Comment: @Strawberry: I see, thank you. Unfortunately, this is the model I have to work with so I can not change this aspect.

Comment: See what @Strawberry wrote and also consider how group by would work against a table column where there is a to-many relationship. One mail with two classifications would generate two rows

Comment: If you cannot change the model then you (probably) would want to count distinct categories.

Comment: As per your input data, Output is correct. Among 5 normal category mail 4 belongs to '2019-01-14 13:53:52' and the rest belongs to '2019-01-21 13:53:52' and your query output is accurate as per Input data and GROUPING. But puzzled what your are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT m.date, c.name, count(*)
FROM Mail m JOIN
     Classification cl
     ON cl.mail_id = m.id JOIN
     Category c
     ON c.id = cl.category_id 
GROUP BY m.date, c.name ;
```

Now that we have gotten that out of the way, your problem is that emails have multiple categories.  So, they are multiply counted.  Hence, the results you are getting are correct.

You have exact duplicates in the classification table, so a simple solution is:

```
SELECT m.date, c.name, count(distinct m.id)
FROM Mail m JOIN
     Classification cl
     ON cl.mail_id = m.id JOIN
     Category c
     ON c.id = cl.category_id 
GROUP BY m.date, c.name ;
```

That said, the real solution is to fix your data, so it doesn't have duplicates.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a410a6/46) is the SQL Fiddle using your data.  You have a "2" for emails on `2019-01-23`.  However, there are no classified emails on that date, so they are not in the results.